# Double loop in Plain TeX

Tags: plain-tex, loops

I want to test double loop in Plain tex but i use latex instead since tex command doesn't work.

Here is an example. I want to use TeX to produce something like this:

1+1 1+2 1+3 1+4

2+1 2+2 2+3 2+4

3+1 3+2 3+3 3+4

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\m \newcount\n
\def\loo{
    \m=1
    \loop\ifnum\m<4 \print \advance\m by 1 \repeat
}
\def\print{
     \n=1
     \loop\ifnum\n<5 \pri \advance\n by 1 \repeat
     \par
}
\def\pri{
     \number\m+\number\n
}

\begin{document}
   \loo
\end{document}
```

I use "pdflatex" to run these file. But what I actually get is:

1+1 1+2 1+3

The out loop doesn't work.

If I use "\loop{something}\ifnum\m<4 \print \ advance\m by 1 \repeat", it would work. I have no idea.