# Produce a table with numbers given by another macro

Tags: tables, loops

I want to create a table with the numbers added by latex itself and the terms are left aligned.
First I ask a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434881/double-loop-in-plain-tex?noredirect=1#comment1090336_434881) about how to produced a multiplication table. And I try to use [`\newenvironment`](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Environments) to deal with it, something like this

```
\newenvironment{boxed}
{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular*}{llllllll}
\hline\\
}
{ 
\\\\\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
}
%--------------------------------------------------
```

but it seems that I am not able to insert my own macro into the definition of `boxed`.
How can I define the environment so that I can use it to produce a formated multiplication table by

```
\begin{boxed}
    \nineij
\end{boxed}
```

where `\nineij` is defined in my `format.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,scale=0.8}

\newcount\loopi \newcount\loopj \newcount\ans
\newcount\nn
\nn=9
\def\nineij{
    \advance\loopi by 1
    \loop{\ninej}\ifnum\loopi<\nn\advance\loopi by1 \repeat
    \vskip 6mm
}

\def\ninej{
    \loopj=1
    \loop{\printij}\ifnum\loopj<\loopi \advance\loopj by1 \repeat
    \par
}
\def\printij{
    \ans=1
    \multiply\ans by \loopi
    \multiply\ans by \loopj
    \number\loopj$\times$\number\loopi = \number\ans$\,$
}


\begin{document}

\nineij

\begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
    1$\times$ 1 = 1\\
    1$\times$ 2 = 2 & 2$\times$ 2 = 4\\
    1$\times$ 3 = 3 & 2$\times$ 3 = 6 & 3$\times$ 3 = 9\\
    1$\times$ 4 = 4 & 2$\times$ 4 = 8 & 3$\times$ 4 = 12 & 4$\times$ 4 = 16\\
    1$\times$ 5 = 5 & 2$\times$ 5 = 10 & 3$\times$ 5 = 15 & 4$\times$ 5 = 20 & 5$\times$ 5 = 25\\
    1$\times$ 6 = 6 & 2$\times$ 6 = 12 & 3$\times$ 6 = 18 & 4$\times$ 6 = 24 & 5$\times$ 6 = 30 & 6$\times$ 6= 36\\
    1$\times$ 7 = 7 & 2$\times$ 7 = 14 & 3$\times$ 7 = 21 & 4$\times$ 7 = 28 & 5$\times$ 7 = 35 & 6$\times$ 7 = 42 & 7$\times$ 7 = 49\\
    1$\times$ 8 = 8 & 2$\times$ 8 = 16 & 3$\times$ 8 = 24 & 4$\times$ 8 = 32 & 5$\times$ 8 = 40 & 6$\times$ 8 = 48 & 7$\times$ 8 = 56 & 8\times 8 = 56\\
    1$\times$ 9 = 9 & 2$\times$ 9 = 18 & 3$\times$ 9 = 27 & 4$\times$ 9 = 36 & 5$\times$ 9 = 45 & 6$\times$ 9 = 54 & 7$\times$ 9 = 63 & 8$\times$ 9 = 72 & 9$\times$ 9 = 81\\
\end{tabular}   


\end{document}
```

Any kind of solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a more generic macro using `expl3`. First we build the table and then output it in one swoop: it's usually complicated to have loops in table cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse,xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\lowertriangular}{mm}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \brooks_lowertriangular:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__brooks_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \brooks_lowertriangular:nn
 {
  % a temporary function for massaging the entries
  \cs_set:Nn \__brooks_inner:nn { #2 }
  % clear the table body
  \tl_clear:N \l__brooks_body_tl
  % outer cycle, #1 rows
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    % inner cycle, ##1 columns
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { ##1 }
     {
      % add the entry for row ##1 (outer cycle) and column ####1 (inner)
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__brooks_body_tl
       { \__brooks_inner:nn { ##1 } { ####1 } }
      % if ##1 = ####1 end the row, otherwise end the cell
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__brooks_body_tl
       { \int_compare:nTF { ##1 = ####1 } { \exp_not:N \\ } { & } }
     }
   }
  % output the table
  \begin{array}{*{#1}{c}} \l__brooks_body_tl \end{array}
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\lowertriangular{9}{#1\times #2}
\]

\[
\lowertriangular{9}{#1\times #2=\inteval{#1*#2}}
\]

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\lowertriangular{5}{a_{#1#2}}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @all I meet latex3 by this answer. I find that egreg's paper on tugboat 40.1 (page 61) is discussing how to use latex3 to solve problems. We can learn by  examples that he writes more detaily. Please check the paper. https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb40-1/tb124complete.pdf Thanks.

Comment: This is the paper on 39.1(part 1) http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121gregorio-expl3.pdf

Comment: 40.1 (part2) http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb40-1/tb124gregorio-templating.pdf

Answer (score 5):

You can use an expandable loop from the LaTeX kernel.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,scale=0.8}

\newcount\loopi \newcount\loopj \newcount\ans

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter

\global\loopi 0
\global\loopj 0

\[\begin{array}{*{9}{l}}
\@whilesw{\ifnum\loopi<9 }\fi
         {\global\advance\loopi 1
          \global\loopj 0
          \@whilesw{\ifnum\loopj<\loopi}\fi
                   {\global\advance\loopj 1
%               
    \ifnum\loopj>1 \@firstofone{&}\fi
    \ans=1
    \multiply\ans by \loopi
    \multiply\ans by \loopj
    \number\loopj\times\number\loopi = \number\ans
%
                   }\\
         }
\end{array}\]

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: one of the reasons you can't use easily your original approach in a tabular is that the cells form groups and the `\loop` makes a definition which is not global. The expandable loops like `\@whilesw` make no definition so they don't have this problem at least that something gets lost after a `&` or `\\ `.

Comment: the reason for the `\@firstofone{&}` is that non-expandable stuff was already executed (`\global\advance..`) and the `&` must then be hidden from TeX else an infamous `\endtemplate` would make the `\ifnum` incomplete.